# Priority Queue Implementation for Kernel Thread Timer Interrupt

Tags: java, algorithm, class, data-structures, operating-system

I'm optimizing my timer interrupt function for kernal threads in Nachos OS.

Introduction [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1993/CSD-93-739.pdf).

I have a class called alarms:

```
public alarms(long wakeTime, KThread my_thread)
{
    wakeTime=wakeTime;
    thread = my_thread;
}

public long getWakeTime()
{
    return wakeTime;
}

public KThread get_my_thread()
{
    return thread;
}
```

I also have a priority queue which is min-heap based:

```
Queue<alarms> my_alarms = new PriorityQueue<alarms>();
```

How do I make the priority queue compare the wakeTime attribute of the alarms class, and generate the min-heap based on that.

In C++ I would overload the operator< function as follows:

```cpp
bool operator<(alarms a, alarms b){return a.wakeTime < b.wakeTime ? true : false;}
```

But I'm not sure how to work with the comparator in java. Can someone please clarify how i would compare the wakeTime attributes in java? Would i need to have my alarms class implement the Comparator class, or how would i go about doing it?

Thank you for your time!
Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it..

```
public class Alarm implements Comparable<Alarm> {
   @Override 
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Alarm a = (Alarm) o; 
        return this.wakeTime - a.wakeTime ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably cast it to Alarm, not Person.